# Scraping HTML inside JSON with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm requesting a website whose response is a JSON like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "response": "<html>... html goes here ...</html>"
}
```

I've seen both ways to scrap HTML or JSON, but haven't found how to scrap HTML inside a JSON. Is it possible to do this using scrapy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to build a `scrapy.Selector` out of the HTML inside the JSON data.

I'll assume you have the `Response` object with JSON data in it, available through `response.text`.

(Below, I'm building a test response to play with (I'm using scrapy 1.1 with Python 3):

```
response = scrapy.http.TextResponse(url='http://www.example.com/json', body=r'''
{
    "success": true,
    "response": "<html>\n <head>\n  <base href='http://example.com/' />\n  <title>Example website</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <div id='images'>\n   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n  </div>\n </body>\n</html>"
}
''', encoding='utf8')
```

)

Using `json` module you can get the HTML data like this:

```
import json
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

You get something like :

```
>>> data
{'success': True, 'response': "<html>\n <head>\n  <base href='http://example.com/' />\n  <title>Example website</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <div id='images'>\n   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>\n  </div>\n </body>\n</html>"}
```

Then you can build a new selector like this:

```
selector = scrapy.Selector(text=data['response'], type="html")
```

after which you can use XPath or CSS selectors on it:

```
>>> selector.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
['Example website']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's another way that you definitely do not need to construct a response object.You can use lxml to parse your html text. You don't need to install any new lib , since Scrapy Selector is based on lxml. Just add the code below to **import lxml** lib.

```
from lxml import etree
```

Here is an exmaple, assuming that the json response is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "htmlinjson": "<html><body> <p id='p1'>p111111</p> <p id='p2'>p22222</p> </html>"
}
```

Extract the html text from the json response by:

```
import json

htmlText = json.loads(response.text)['htmlinjson']
```

Then construct a lxml xpath selcector using:

```
from lxml import etree

resultPage = etree.HTML(htmlText)
```

Now use the lxml selector to extract text of the node

with id="p1", basing on xpath just like how scrapy xpath selector do:

```
print resultPage.xpath('//p[@id="p1"]')[0].text
```

You will get:

> p111111

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try json.loads(initial_response) , so you get a dict and can use his keys, like ['response']